# Do I need to add older dependencies in my package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

In my app project I'm using the npm package `graphql` in the version 0.13.1. and `apollo-cache-inmemory` in version 1.1.9.

Running `npm install` gives me the warning

```
npm WARN apollo-cache-inmemory@1.1.9 requires a peer of graphql@0.11.7 || ^0.12.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

So my installed graphql is newer, then the version which is required by the apollo-cache-inmemory.

This is just an example and I do not understand how to handle this cases.

Of course I can ignore this warning - as everything is working fine - but I would like to understand that issue and in best case I would eliminate those warnings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that your graphql version (`0.13.1`) does not fulfill the peer dependency requirement set by apollo-cache-inmemory (`^0.12.0`). The peer dependency declaration in `apollo-cache-inmemory` in general specifies a needed dependency, that is not included as package dependency but has to be provided by the user of the package. Peer dependencies are specified together with a compatible version range.

The reason for your warning here is, that "major zero" versions are handled differently than "normal versions" beginning with `1.0.0`. A caret specifier with a major zero version behaves the same as the tilde specifier with normal versions, i.e. `^0.12.0` only matches everything below `0.13.0` (see [here](http://nodesource.com/blog/semver-tilde-and-caret/) for a good explanation.

Unfortunately the only way to get rid of the warning is, (1) to use a "compatible" graphql version (i.e. `0.12.X`), (2) have the `apollo-cache-inmemory` project reference a newer one (e.g. `^0.13.0`) or (3) let graphql change their versions to standard versions beginning with `1.0.0`.

As (2) and (3) are not really likely to happen, you could do (1) :)

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by `apollo-cache-in-memory@1.1.9` specifying a `peerDependency` on `graphql@0.11.7 || ^0.12.0`:

```
# In a terminal session
λ npm show apollo-cache-inmemory@1.1.9 .peerDependencies.graphql
0.11.7 || ^0.12.0
```

`0.13.1` is not covered by the version range `0.11.7 || ^0.12.0`, to the warning you see is emitted.

That being said there might be no actual interop issue between `graphql` and `apollo-cache-in-memory`. The peer dependency range tells us only about the `graphql` versions the authors tested against.

---

There are two ways to get rid of this warning:

1. Open a PR at [apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/b1be7b664f348176b5ecdd979830a5780e1f1453/packages/apollo-cache-inmemory/package.json#L47) to update their `graphql` `peerDependency` to something like the following and update to the subsequent release

   ```
   0.11.7 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0
   ```
2. Downgrade `graphql` to a compatible version range, e.g. `graphql@0.12`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite if it's right and secure, but changing the peer version in package.json of each 'problematic' dependency in node_modules to current ones could help you to get rid of all these errors without any trouble. For example, I faced the same problem with the following npm warnings:

```
npm WARN react-dom@16.8.1 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-ellipsis-text@1.1.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.4.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-pose@4.0.7 requires a peer of react@^16.3.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-redux@6.0.1 requires a peer of react@^16.4.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Installing the latest version of React didn't help. So I just edited package.json of react-dom, react-ellipsis, react-pose and react-redux modules and changed required React version to 16.4.0:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^16.4.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.8.1"
},
```

All the warnings are gone now. 
Hope it helps.